# In general, $\textit{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2$

Tags: statistics

This is from page 25 of [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441926135):

> In general, it may be shown that
>   $$\textit{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2$$

I can't remember ever seeing that "In general" elsewhere.

So if this identity only holds "in general" are there cases where 
$$\textit{Var}(X) \neq E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2$$

Even in cases where there is no second moment, I think the identity should hold. Because neither the variance nor the second moment exist. But maybe this is what they're talking about.

Comment: I think you're just reading 'in general' as in the common language use 'almost always.' the author though means 'holds w/o further assumptions', and you agree (existence of second moment an obvious precondition).

Comment: Yes, mathematicians use the expression "in general" to mean "always" or "in all cases", whereas in everyday informal language, "in general" sometimes just means "usually".

This is a bit unfortunate, and I'll try to bear this in mind the next time I have reason to say "in general" in class!

Comment: In general means not merely in the kind of cases we've been considering, but in all cases.  To say that it holds in general means precisely that there are _no_ cases where the identity fails to hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ has no second moment, then the formula does not make sense because $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ is not defined.

If $X$ *has* second moment, then the formula holds without any additional assumptions---it follows easily from the definition of $\mathrm{Var}(X)$.